# Return values of one-to-many association

Tags: knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have this two models with one-to-many association.

```
const Organization = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: "organization",
  idAttribute: "idorganization",
  members: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(Member);
  }
});

const Member = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: "member",
  idAttribute: "idmember",
  organization: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Organization);
  }
});
```

`Organization` have many member and one `member` have only one organization.

Then, I need list all member of one specific organization. I tried with

```
router.get("/list", (req, res) => {
  Organization.forge({
    idorganization: req.body.idorganization
  }).fetch().then((ret) => {
    res.send(ret.members()); // it's not work!
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  });
});
```

But, the command `ret.members()` not work as expected. Why? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
router.get("/list", (req, res) => {
  Organization.forge({
    idorganization: req.body.idorganization
  }).fetch({withRelated:["members"]}).then((ret) => {
    res.send(ret.members); 
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  });
});
```

More useful info: http://bookshelfjs.org/#my-relations-dont-seem-to-be-loading-whats-up